# grails: is conditional markup in a gsp page possible just using ${}

Tags: grails, gsp

Grails of course has the built in "if" and "else" tag, e.g.

```
 <g:if test="${name == 'Fred'}">
     Hello Fred, welcome back from your trip!
 </g:if>
 <g:else>
     Hello ${name}
 </g:else>
```

Is it possible to so something like this purely using the ${} capability on a gsp page?  Not using the

```
   <g:if> and 
   <g:else>
```

tags?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, e.g. like this:

```
Hello ${name}${name == "Fred" ? ", welcome back from your trip!" : ""}
```

Comment: Ah yes, forgot this conditional expression construct, great, thanks.  Cannot except it as an answer for 7 more minutes for some reason.

Comment: This isn't an usage of elvis operator.