# Groovy server page, creating a table

Tags: grails, groovy, gsp

I have a situation where my domain has two fields such as

```
Class test{
   static constraints {
     testno(nullable:true)
     opt(nullable:false, blank:false)
   }

   Double testno
   String opt
}
```

The `opt` has option values such as 'test', 'try', and 'final'.

Now I need to create a table in .gsp file using the above info such that

```
----------------------------------
         Test        Try       Final
-------------------------------------
TestNo   
-------------------------------------
```

The value for each `opt` is display as testNo in the row below.

I am not sure how to start here. I tried creating a table such that:

````
```<%
def column=[
['field':'Test'],
['field': 'Try'],
['field':'Final']
]
%>```
````

However, how do I add row in the table?
In addition, how can I use the table in a different gsp table given that

```
class Result(){ test(nullable:true) hasMany=[test:Test]}
```

I would like it to render the table.gsp in result.gsp

Comment: Do you want to display an X or something below `Test`, `Try` or `Final` in the table to indicate which value a particular record has?

Comment: Yes, thank you for responding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send all your tests to the view in your controller:

```
def showTests() {
    // your controller code
    [tests: Test.findAll()]
}
```

Then, render the data using gsp tags in your view file (e.g. `showTests.gsp`):

```
<html>
   <body>
     <table>
     <tr>
       <th></th>
       <th>Test</th>
       <th>Try</th>
       <th>Final</th>
     </tr>
    
     <g:each in="${tests}" var="t">
      <tr>
        <td>${t.testno}</td>
        <td>${t.opt == "test" ? "x" : ""}</td>
        <td>${t.opt == "try" ? "x" : ""}</td>
        <td>${t.opt == "final" ? "x" : ""}</td>
      </tr>
     </g:each>
    </table>

   </body>
</html>
```

This is just a very simple solution to your problem.

### Using it as a subresource

If your Tests are contained in another resource like Result, you can access them in two ways.

If you send your entire report to your view you can use:

```
// controller
def showResult() {
    // your controller code
    [result: Result.get(/*id...*/)]
}

// showResult.gsp view, just change this line
<g:each in="${result.tests}" var="t">
```

Otherwise, if you want to send only tests to your existing view from the main example above:

```
// controller
def showTests() {
    // your controller code
    def result = Result.get(/*your id*/)
    [tests: result.tests]
}
```

Comment: Thanks@lifeisfoo. What if the table needs to be displayed in GSP tags for another domain/controller. For instance: ```class Result(){ test(nullable:true) hasMany=[test:Test]}```

Comment: Please @Sam update your question so I can update my answer

Comment: @Sam check it out

Comment: Oh! is ```def report = Result.get(id)```? I think my question wasn't as clear I want it to be. I want the ```Result``` 's view to display the table on its page.

Comment: it was a typo, just update the Result's controller to send the result object (solution 1) or send to the view only the tests (solution 2).

Comment: The solution with some tweak seems to work, but the problem is that the lines of codes `    <td>${t.testno}</td>
        <td>${t.opt == "test" ? "x" : ""}</td>
     ` shows value for testno, but the value under test is always 'x'

Comment: Check your db data because the code is right: also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/19437085/3340702. Moreover, keep in mind that the  equal operator is case sensitive, so "test" is not equal to "Test". Please accept the answer since it solves your initial question. If you have other problem due to text comparison, ask another question.